# refresh TextBox every second I want to show Digital Clock (Windows App)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, window

C# code

```
TextTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Want to refresh this text box every second

Or show a Digital Clock any Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to add a timer to your app and do it as shown:

Form Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   txtdate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(("dddd" + ("," + "MM-dd-yyyy")));
   Timer1.Interval = 1000;
   Timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Timer Tick:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   txtTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615945(v=vs.95).aspx):

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)
};
timer.Tick += (o, e) =>
{
    TextTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
};
timer.Start();
```

Comment: @MoeezAgha What exactly isn't working? I just did a quick check and put the code in the MainPage constructor of a WP7.1 application, where `TextTime` is a TextBlock on the MainPage. Works as expected.